Как получить токен для другого ip-адреса?
Моя основная задача - хотя бы сделать пост от имени пользователя кодом. Для этого необходим токен, однако, он привязывается к айпишнику, а на машине где запускается код он другой, что я могу сделать, что бы получить право делать посты?

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с более внятного заголовка

Так я его и не могу использовать. Это и есть основная проблема. Я пытаюсь узнать как можно получить токен с oauth на машине, что бы совпадал айпи и я мог пользоваться vk api

А, вот так. Спасибо

Какой именно токен вам нужен? В ВК их четыре вида: сервисный токен приложения, Refresh token, Access token и ID token. И вы уверены, что токен привязан к IP адресу? Это мал-мало сомнительно.

Мне нужен токен пользователя. Без него я не могу постить. Я его смог получить с параметрами offline и wall, но всё так же у меян не получается сделать пост ошибка: Access denied: no access to call this method. It cannot be called with current scopes
